# Simplify $\frac{d}{dt}\int_x^t f(t,y)dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I am trying to simplify $\frac{d}{dt}\int_x^t f(t,y)dy$ as a part of a proof.

I am somewhat confused on how I can proceed with this. Do I define a function $g(t,y)$ such that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = f(x,t)$ and then say $\frac{d}{dt}\int_x^t f(t,y)dy = \frac{d}{dt}(g(t,t) - g(t,x))$?

Or can I just say that $\frac{d}{dt}\int_x^t f(t,y)dy = \frac{d}{dt}(f(t,t) - f(t,x))$? If so why can I say this.

Also note that I am trying to avoid using leibniz integral rule since it has not been covered yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of the integral as being a function of three parameters:

$$g(a,b,c) = \int_a^b f(c,y)\:dy$$

Thus the derivative you want can be derived from chain rule

$$\frac{d}{dt}g(a(t),b(t),c(t)) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial a}\frac{da}{dt} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial b}\frac{db}{dt} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial c}\frac{dc}{dt}$$

$$= 0 + f(t,t) +\int_x^t \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,y)\:dy $$

Comment: This is of course right, and how I approached the problem, but evaluating $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial c}$ is pretty much the Leibniz integral rule, which OP wants to avoid (though I'm not sure that it is possible to avoid it in some form or another).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I assumed by Leibniz integral rule OP meant the whole version which includes time dependence in the bounds as well as the integrand and thought perhaps that was the point of confusion. But there are a lot of "Leibniz integral rules" so clarification would be nice.

Comment: For reference @NinadMunshi I meant not using the full blown integral rule here:https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/6dce99ebdae5be6b988baba1d74afdedaaab2c7f which is from here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Also @NinadMunshi could you explain how you got that last line given the first line?

Comment: @Geralt you're gonna have to be more specific with your questions. What exactly confuses you?

Comment: I'm confused on how you applied $\frac{\partial g}{\partial b}\frac{db}{dt}$ to get $f(t,t)$ and how you applied $\frac{\partial g}{\partial c}\frac{dc}{dt}$ to get $\int_x^t \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,y)dy$.

Comment: @Geralt take a look at the [proof provided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Alternative_Proof_of_General_Form_with_Variable_Limits,_using_the_Chain_Rule). Here, the calculation of $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial b}$ is done using Fundamental theorem of calculus, while $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial c}$ is done using the basic form of the theorem. (Btw Ninad your first line should be $g(a,b,c) = \int_a^b f(c,y)\, dy$)